# ArrayAdapter requires ID to be a TextView error

Tags: android, listview, textview, android-arrayadapter, android-relativelayout

I am trying to create a nice layout for my list items, but my code only works when it is simplified like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:textSize="16sp" >
</TextView>
```

When I add a little bit more it compiles and runs but it force closes on start and gives me the error `ArrayAdapter requires ID to be a TextView`:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:padding="6dip" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="6dip"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/secondLine"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="26dip"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/icon1"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="Some more information" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@id/secondLine"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/icon1"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="Some Information" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="6dip"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

and

```
public class FirstLoginActivity extends ListActivity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        String[] testcontacts = getResources().getStringArray(
                R.array.testcontacts_array);
        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_items,
                testcontacts));

        ListView lv = getListView();
        lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                // When clicked, show a toast with the TextView text
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        ((TextView) view).getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
```

I am pretty sure I'm doing this right, I've been through numerous tutorials and I've found that the fastest and most efficient way is to create a static `ViewHolder` class.  One of the tutorials tried accessing the data directly which is what I was trying to do.  I'm still a little confused on how to do so.

```
    public class FirstLoginActivity extends ListActivity {
    Context mContext;
    List mList;

    String[] testcontacts = getResources().getStringArray(
            R.array.testcontacts_array);

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_items,
                testcontacts));

        ListView lv = getListView();
        lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                // When clicked, show a toast with the TextView text
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        ((TextView) view).getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }



    public View getView(int position, View convertview, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        View v = convertview;
        if (v == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) LayoutInflater
                    .from(mContext);
            v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_items, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.firstLine = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.firstLine);
            holder.secondLine = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.secondLine);
            holder.icon1 = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.icon1);
            holder.icon2 = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.icon2);
            v.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();
        }
        holder.firstLine.setText(testcontacts[position]);
        holder.secondLine.setText(testcontacts[position]);
        // holder.icon1.setImageBitmap((position & 1) == 1 ? mIcon1: mIcon2);
        //call the images directly?
        return v;
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        TextView firstLine;
        TextView secondLine;
        ImageView icon1;
        ImageView icon2;

    }
}
```

Comment: follow the first answer from the below link
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9280965/arrayadapter-requires-the-resource-id-to-be-a-textview-xml-problems][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9280965/arrayadapter-requires-the-resource-id-to-be-a-textview-xml-problems

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably using something like this ([here the doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html)):

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.layout_1, values);
```

in that case your layout must be a simple layout with a TextView.

If you wanna use your own layout you need to write a custom adapter.

Answer (score 1):

Build your own ArrayAdapter, then you can make the layout work however you would like.

Comment: Also, ArrayAdapter has another constructor which takes any resource as an input and you can specify TextView id used for populating http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#ArrayAdapter(android.content.Context, int, int, T[]) .

Comment: Can you direct me to a good tutorial that could teach me how to create my own listAdapter?

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wDBM6wVEO70 Is the developers explaining how listviews work, and how to make them work right.

Comment: Thanks that Video really helped alot, but now i'm stuck at accessing my information directly to show in my listview.

Answer (score 0):

The ArrayAdapter requires the resource ID to be a TextView XML exception means you don't supply what the ArrayAdapter expects. When you use this constructor:

```
new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.a_layout_file, this.file)
```

`R.Layout.a_layout_file` must be the id of a xml layout file containing only a TextView(the TextView can't be wrapped by another layout, like a LinearLayout, RelativeLayout etc!), something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    // other attributes of the TextView
/>
```

If you want your list row layout to be something a little different then a simple TextView widget use this constructor:

```
new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.a_layout_file, 
   R.id.the_id_of_a_textview_from_the_layout, this.file)
```

where you supply the id of a layout that can contain various views, but also must contain a TextView with and id(the third parameter) that you pass to your ArrayAdapter so it can know where to put the Strings in the row layout.

Comment: What if my ArrayAdapter uses cell which is custom layout and have many text views in the cell?

Comment: It wont be a problem. Instead of single button or textview, You can use multiple views in the arrayadapter. @NinjaCoder

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be on the right lines.  I'm not sure the exact issue with your code as I've not compared closely, but it works in [this example](http://easyway2in.blogspot.co.uk/2014/09/android-listview-with-custom-layout.html).

The full tutorial is here: [Android tutorial for beginners - 97 - ListView with Custom Layout](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gAIB4fTm2BA)

This avoids the error `ArrayAdapter requires ID to be a TextView` which I was also getting.