# Android ListView exception issue

Tags: android, listview, exception

I am trying populate a listView from a string array but I keep getting the following very long and complex exception report:

```
02-16 20:00:24.119: E/AndroidRuntime(17608): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-16 20:00:24.119: E/AndroidRuntime(17608): android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f080003 type #0x12 is not valid
02-16 20:00:24.119: E/AndroidRuntime(17608):    at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:1874)
02-16 20:00:24.119: E/AndroidRuntime(17608):    at android.content.res.Resources.getLayout(Resources.java:731)
02-16 20:00:24.119: E/AndroidRuntime(17608):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:318)
02-16 20:00:24.119: E/AndroidRuntime(17608):    at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:332)
02-16 20:00:24.119: E/AndroidRuntime(17608):    at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:323)
02-16 20:00:24.119: E/AndroidRuntime(17608):    at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:1315)
02-16 20:00:24.119: E/AndroidRuntime(17608):    at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1198)
02-16 20:00:24.119: E/AndroidRuntime(17608):    at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1109)
02-16 20:00:24.119: E/AndroidRuntime(17608):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8172)
02-16 20:00:24.119: E/AndroidRuntime(17608):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3140)
02-16 20:00:24.119: E/AndroidRuntime(17608):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1012)
02-16 20:00:24.119: E/AndroidRuntime(17608):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:381)
02-16 20:00:24.119: E/AndroidRuntime(17608):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:304)
02-16 20:00:24.119: E/AndroidRuntime(17608):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8172)
02-16 20:00:24.119: E/AndroidRuntime(17608):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3140)
02-16 20:00:24.119: E/AndroidRuntime(17608):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:245)
02-16 20:00:24.119: E/AndroidRuntime(17608):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8172)
02-16 20:00:24.119: E/AndroidRuntime(17608):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:526)
02-16 20:00:24.119: E/AndroidRuntime(17608):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:304)
02-16 20:00:24.119: E/AndroidRuntime(17608):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8172)
02-16 20:00:24.119: E/AndroidRuntime(17608):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3140)
02-16 20:00:24.119: E/AndroidRuntime(17608):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:245)
02-16 20:00:24.119: E/AndroidRuntime(17608):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8172)
02-16 20:00:24.119: E/AndroidRuntime(17608):    at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:805)
02-16 20:00:24.119: E/AndroidRuntime(17608):    at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1744)
02-16 20:00:24.119: E/AndroidRuntime(17608):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-16 20:00:24.119: E/AndroidRuntime(17608):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:144)
02-16 20:00:24.119: E/AndroidRuntime(17608):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4937)
02-16 20:00:24.119: E/AndroidRuntime(17608):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-16 20:00:24.119: E/AndroidRuntime(17608):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
02-16 20:00:24.119: E/AndroidRuntime(17608):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858)
02-16 20:00:24.119: E/AndroidRuntime(17608):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
02-16 20:00:24.119: E/AndroidRuntime(17608):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-16 20:00:25.789: I/Process(17608): Sending signal. PID: 17608 SIG: 9
```

The following is my Activity class:

```
public class ArticlesActivity extends BaseActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.articles);

        String[] items = {"line#1", "line#2", "line#3", "line#4"};
        ListView articlesList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.articlesList);

//      ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.article_item, items);
//      ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.article_item, R.id.articlesList, items);
//      ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.articles, R.id.articleItem, items);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.id.articleItem, items);

        articlesList.setAdapter(adapter);

    }
}
```

Here's my ArticlesList.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/articlesContainer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/articlesList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

And here's my Article_item.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="left|right"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/articleItem"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView" />

</LinearLayout>

<!-- <TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/articleItem"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" /> -->
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9280965/arrayadapter-requires-the-resource-id-to-be-a-textview-xml-problems) question mirrors my situation and I tried adjusting my Article_item.xml to have just a TextView (which is commented out) but it made no difference.

Comment: first of all are you sure that you are including the right xml files in your activity?

Comment: code seems fine..try cleaning the project...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try your xml **Article_item.xml** like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>   
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/TV_articleItem"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TextView" />
```

and use this in your activity

```
String[] items = {"line#1", "line#2", "line#3", "line#4"};
ListView articlesList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.articlesList);
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.Article_item, R.id.TV_articleItem, items);
articlesList.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: Thanks for this. In the ArrayAdapter constructor I was using the ArticlesList layout and the ArticleItem resource rather than the ArticleItem layout and the ArticleItem resource. Your help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Please try this:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.Article_item, items);
```