# ListView Crash FATAL EXCEPTION

Tags: java, android, listview, arraylist

I have a `ListView` to display content from `ArrayList`. I am calling `listView.setAdapter` from my method.

---

In my app i can accses the topten_activity from th main_actiivty or if i end game i got and intent that refers me to add data to(Person);
my Topten_activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/bg_1"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
</ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

---

Whenever launching the activity/intent. the application is crashing

```
FATAL EXCEPRION:main.
```

i used `Log.d` in my method which set adapter. The log gets printed, so the call is reaching there

Please look at my code below

**Code:**

```
public class TopTen extends ListActivity{

Person p;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_topten);
    Log.d("inside", "TopTen OnCreat");
    populateListView();
}

private void populateListView(){
    Log.d("inside", "populateListView");
    ArrayAdapter<Person> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Person>(this, R.layout.activity_topten,p.TopTen);
    ListView list =(ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);
}   
}
```

**StackTrace:**

```
 FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 Process: com.example.flagsgame, PID: 29436
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.flagsgame/com.example.flagsgame.TopTen}: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2212)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2271)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1205)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5146)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:796)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:612)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.example.flagsgame.TopTen.populateListView(TopTen.java:26)
    at com.example.flagsgame.TopTen.onCreate(TopTen.java:21)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2169)
```

**Person.class:**

```
public class Person extends Activity{

EditText name;
Button ok;
TextView enter;
Integer Score;
String Name;
Person person;
Person a;
Person b;
Person c;

//Map<String,Integer>Names=new HashMap<String,Integer>(10); 
ArrayList<Person>TopTen = new ArrayList<Person>(10);
//Map sortedMap;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_person);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    Score = intent.getIntExtra("Score", 0);
    name =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.namep);
    ok =(Button)findViewById(R.id.send);
    enter =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.entername);
    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Lets see if you are can be on TopTen", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);

    a.Name="Daniel";
    a.Score=20;
    b.Name="Zohar";
    b.Score=15;
    c.Name="Yakir";
    c.Score=10;

    TopTen.add(a);
    TopTen.add(b);
    TopTen.add(c);

    ok.setOnClickListener(SendActionListener);
}

private OnClickListener SendActionListener = new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Person lastEntry = TopTen.get(TopTen.size()-1);//Last element of the arraylist
        if(lastEntry.Score < Score){//checking score
            lastEntry.Score = Score;//put score aka Value
            lastEntry.Name=name.getText().toString();//put name aka Key
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You are now on the TopTen List", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        }
    };

};

}//end of Person
```

Comment: Which one is the first Activity Person or TopTen ?

Comment: If iam in the main so i can go first to the TopTen but if iam in the Game so Person Will be first

Comment: Ok There is a problem in this. I will explain in answer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android ListView exception issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14914903/android-listview-exception-issue)

Comment: by your link i understand i need to make Textview that will contian the list?@AkhilJain

Comment: @Adi.. Read answer from Amsheer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't initialized your `Person` class on `onCreate()` method that's why `p.TopTen` is null. So you need to do it by

```
 p = new Person();
```

Comment: I have one doubt. If initialise like this then need to create a constructor in Person class right? And Person is Activity. Is it work? I want to know. I think your answer will work.

Comment: If `Person` class is activity then you can't initiate activity. Instead of you can make a public static variable in that activity and access by `Person.yourVarName`

Comment: But in this question Person is Activity so only i got confused.

Comment: No but before that i didn't know.  But if its a activity then need to access by public static variable.

Comment: Your answer is accepted so i think it will work. Thanks for the information @PiyushGupta

Answer (score 0):

`Person p;` has not been initialized

Comment: but this is how i need to define it no?

Comment: I don't know. I only know your error is NPE caused by line 26 in method TopTen#populateListView and I see that p has not been initialized.

Comment: @Adi... inmyth is right initalize variable `p`. then call for list adapter. see the call `ArrayAdapter<Person> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Person>(this, R.layout.activity_topten,p.TopTen);`  the variable need to initialized palin and simple. In your case `p.TopTen` is => `null.TopTen`

Comment: ok so before that i tried many ways to installize it and failed any idea how to? cause its and person object

Answer (score 0):

There is one problem in your code. That is you are get ArrayList value from one activity to another. And there is one more point you mention in comment not two activity get called only one called. In that case you initialise or not that doesn't matter you may get null pointer.

So the peaceful solution just initialise the ArrayList in its own Activity.

For example:

In your TopTen Activity initialise ArrayList

```
ArrayList<Person>TopTen_array = new ArrayList<Person>(10);
```

Add values to ArrayList in onCreate

```
 a.Name="Daniel";
        a.Score=20;
        b.Name="Zohar";
        b.Score=15;
        c.Name="Yakir";
        c.Score=10;

        TopTen_array.add(a);
        TopTen_array.add(b);
        TopTen_array.add(c);
```

And replace your following line

```
ArrayAdapter<Person> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Person>(this, R.layout.activity_topten,p.TopTen);
```

with this

```
ArrayAdapter<Person> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Person>(this, R.layout.activity_topten,TopTen_array);
```

Comment: When i replace the ArrayAdapter

Comment: I understood Check the answer now TopTen is your Activity name so you must get that error. Sorry i didn't notice that first. Check now.

Comment: Still the same error and thats because the TopTen arraylist is from Person class am i right?hh

Comment: No. I mention that you must initialise TopTen_array in TopTen Activity. Outside onCreate method. Did you do that ?

Comment: TopTen_array; did that but its dosent contain nothing didnt get you

Comment: Did you do this in onCreate
 TopTen_array.add(a); in TopTen Activity

Comment: i think you kind of confusse about that lets me clear that the Arraylist is came from the person class not from the TopTen which me i got to import it to the TopTen class by an object