# Listview not updating on search

Tags: android, android-listview, android-xml

I am creating my first list view in Android. I have successfully query an api, get the results and put them in their own object and add each object to an array list. I have that all running well, but the list is not updating.

This is where I get my data from the returned json and add the items to the list then try to update my list view:

```
//get json items
                for(int i = 0; i < json.getJSONArray("data").length(); i++) {

                    String beerId = GetBeerDataFromJSON(i,"id", json);
                    String beerName = GetBeerDataFromJSON(i,"name", json);
                    String beerDescription = GetBeerDataFromJSON(i,"description" , json);
                    String beerAbv = GetBeerDataFromJSON(i,"abv" , json);
                    String beerIbu = GetBeerDataFromJSON(i,"ibu" , json);
                    String beerIcon = GetBeerIconsFromJSON(i, "icon",json );
                    String beerMediumIcon = GetBeerIconsFromJSON(i, "medium",json );
                    String beerGlass = GetBeerGlassFromJSON(i, json );
                    String beerStyle = GetBeerStyleFromJSON(i,"name", json );
                    String beerStyleDescription = GetBeerStyleFromJSON(i,"description", json );
                    String beerBreweryId = GetBeerBreweryInfoFromJSON(i, "id", json );
                    String beerBreweryName = GetBeerBreweryInfoFromJSON(i, "name", json );
                    String beerBreweryDescription = GetBeerBreweryInfoFromJSON(i, "description", json );
                    String beerBreweryWebsite = GetBeerBreweryInfoFromJSON(i, "website", json );
                    String beerBreweryYear = GetBeerBreweryInfoFromJSON(i, "established", json );



                    //create beer object
                    BeerData thisBeer = new BeerData(beerName, beerId, beerDescription, beerAbv, beerIbu, beerIcon,
                            beerMediumIcon, beerGlass, beerStyle, beerStyleDescription, beerBreweryId, beerBreweryName,
                            beerBreweryDescription, beerBreweryYear, beerBreweryWebsite);

                    //add beer to list
                    beerList.add(thisBeer);


                }

                //update listview

                ArrayAdapter<BeerData> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<BeerData>(MainActivity.this,R.layout.list_item);

                lv.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
```

my list_item xml is:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

<TextView android:id="@+id/itemName" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

my main_activity.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" >
    </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Update**

Thanks to some answer below I realized I wasnt passing the data list through the adapter. Now that I do that I get this error:

```
06-18 09:34:37.631: E/AndroidRuntime(13761): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-18 09:34:37.631: E/AndroidRuntime(13761): java.lang.IllegalStateException: ArrayAdapter requires the resource ID to be a TextView
06-18 09:34:37.631: E/AndroidRuntime(13761):    at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:386)
06-18 09:34:37.631: E/AndroidRuntime(13761):    at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:362)
06-18 09:34:37.631: E/AndroidRuntime(13761):    at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2159)
06-18 09:34:37.631: E/AndroidRuntime(13761):    at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1246)
06-18 09:34:37.631: E/AndroidRuntime(13761):    at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1158)
06-18 09:34:37.631: E/AndroidRuntime(13761):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15525)
06-18 09:34:37.631: E/AndroidRuntime(13761):    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChild(RelativeLayout.java:666)
06-18 09:34:37.631: E/AndroidRuntime(13761):    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:477)
06-18 09:34:37.631: E/AndroidRuntime(13761):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15525)
06-18 09:34:37.631: E/AndroidRuntime(13761):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4825)
06-18 09:34:37.631: E/AndroidRuntime(13761):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
06-18 09:34:37.631: E/AndroidRuntime(13761):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15525)
06-18 09:34:37.631: E/AndroidRuntime(13761):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:847)
06-18 09:34:37.631: E/AndroidRuntime(13761):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
06-18 09:34:37.631: E/AndroidRuntime(13761):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15525)
06-18 09:34:37.631: E/AndroidRuntime(13761):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4825)
06-18 09:34:37.631: E/AndroidRuntime(13761):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
06-18 09:34:37.631: E/AndroidRuntime(13761):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2434)
06-18 09:34:37.631: E/AndroidRuntime(13761):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15525)
06-18 09:34:37.631: E/AndroidRuntime(13761):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1874)
06-18 09:34:37.631: E/AndroidRuntime(13761):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1089)
06-18 09:34:37.631: E/AndroidRuntime(13761):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1265)
06-18 09:34:37.631: E/AndroidRuntime(13761):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:989)
06-18 09:34:37.631: E/AndroidRuntime(13761):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4351)
06-18 09:34:37.631: E/AndroidRuntime(13761):    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:749)
06-18 09:34:37.631: E/AndroidRuntime(13761):    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:562)
06-18 09:34:37.631: E/AndroidRuntime(13761):    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:532)
06-18 09:34:37.631: E/AndroidRuntime(13761):    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:735)
06-18 09:34:37.631: E/AndroidRuntime(13761):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
06-18 09:34:37.631: E/AndroidRuntime(13761):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
06-18 09:34:37.631: E/AndroidRuntime(13761):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-18 09:34:37.631: E/AndroidRuntime(13761):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5226)
06-18 09:34:37.631: E/AndroidRuntime(13761):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-18 09:34:37.631: E/AndroidRuntime(13761):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-18 09:34:37.631: E/AndroidRuntime(13761):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:795)
06-18 09:34:37.631: E/AndroidRuntime(13761):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:562)
06-18 09:34:37.631: E/AndroidRuntime(13761):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-18 09:34:37.631: E/AndroidRuntime(13761): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.TextView
06-18 09:34:37.631: E/AndroidRuntime(13761):    at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:379)
```

Comment: from your previous question have you extended activity of listactivity?.

Comment: MainActivity extends ListActivity

Comment: extend activity not list activity and usse beerlist to set data to listview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have seen your previous question which is related to the one above.

Your class should extend `Activity`.

Your listitem.xml looks like

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

<TextView android:id="@+id/itemName"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Use the ArrayAdapter constructor appropriately.

```
ArrayAdapter<BeerData> adapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<BeerData>(MainActivity.this, R.layout.listitem, R.id.itemname, beerlist);
```

Also in your comments you said you were getting arrayadapter constructor undefined. This is because you were using `this`. Use a activity context like `MainActivity.this`.

For more info check the below link

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html

Answer (score 1):

where are you using the beerlist to show it in list view?

Try different constructor for array adapter with option to place your list inside constructor.
for ex: like this 
ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(MainActivity.this,R.layout.list_item, beerList);

Comment: use this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9280965/arrayadapter-requires-the-resource-id-to-be-a-textview-xml-problems

Answer (score 1):

set tha array with adapter

```
ArrayAdapter<BeerData> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<BeerData>(MainActivity.this,R.layout.list_item, beerList);

      lv.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
```

Comment: that makes sense, since I wasnt passing any data too it... but I got to this error now:

http://pastebin.com/w0HmRY0Z

Comment: android.R.layout.list_item use this with that adapter in adapter

Comment: @Mike ArrayAdapter<BeerList> adapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<BeerList>(this, R.layout.row, R.id.textView1, beerlist); define row.xml with a textview with id textView 1 and set adapter to listview

Comment: ok, so my main contains an arrayList with id list. Then I have a list_item.xml which is the list item xml which has a text view called itemName.

    ArrayAdapter<BeerData> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<BeerData>(android.R.id.list,R.layout.list_item,R.id.itemName, beerList);

This did not work

Comment: @Mike `ArrayAdapter<BeerData> adapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<BeerData>(this, R.layout.listitem, R.id.textView1, beerlist);`. `listitem.xml`  should have `textview` with `textview1` and your activity class should extend activty not listactivity. this continued from previous question

Comment: @Mike check this http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html. check the arrayadapter constructors

Comment: http://pastebin.com/u5Tdvu4M and getting arrayadapter constructor undefined. My list_item.xml is this http://pastebin.com/jGAvXnmj

Comment: @Mike instead of `this` use `activityName.this`

Comment: Yes, thank you so much for spending some extra time with me. I have some small visual problems but I can fix them. Thanks again for really taking the time to help, I appreciate it!

Comment: i will post this as an answer coz it actually solves your problem and for clarity so accept the same

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass list data in a string array.

```
//Fill this array with strings that can be shown in the list
String[] arrStrBeerData;

ArrayAdapter<BeerData> alAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<BeerData>(context, textViewResourceId, arrStrBeerData);
lv.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
```

Or

You can create custom adapter by extending BaseAdapter, passing data to the adapter