# Using complex header layouts in listview

Tags: android, listview

I have an android app that populates a listview with a custom adapter. This adapter adds sections to the listview with headers. This adapter is shown below:

```
public class SeparatedListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {  

    public final Map<String,Adapter> sections = new LinkedHashMap<String,Adapter>();  
    public final ArrayAdapter<String> headers;  
    public final static int TYPE_SECTION_HEADER = 0;        

    public SeparatedListAdapter(Context context) {  
        headers = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context, R.layout.list_header);
    }

    public void addSection(String section, Adapter adapter) {  
        this.headers.add(section);  
        this.sections.put(section, adapter);
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {  
        for(Object section : this.sections.keySet()) {  
            Adapter adapter = sections.get(section);  
            int size = adapter.getCount() + 1;  

            // check if position inside this section   
            if(position == 0) return section;  
            if(position < size) return adapter.getItem(position - 1);  

            // otherwise jump into next section  
            position -= size;  
        }  
        return null;  
    }  

    public int getCount() {  
        // total together all sections, plus one for each section header  
        int total = 0;  
        for(Adapter adapter : this.sections.values())  
            total += adapter.getCount() + 1;  
        return total;  
    }  

    public int getViewTypeCount() {  
        // assume that headers count as one, then total all sections  
        int total = 1;  
        for(Adapter adapter : this.sections.values())  
            total += adapter.getViewTypeCount();  
        return total;  
    }  

    public int getItemViewType(int position) {  
        int type = 1;  
        for(Object section : this.sections.keySet()) {  
            Adapter adapter = sections.get(section);  
            int size = adapter.getCount() + 1;  

            // check if position inside this section   
            if(position == 0) return TYPE_SECTION_HEADER;  
            if(position < size) return type + adapter.getItemViewType(position - 1);  

            // otherwise jump into next section  
            position -= size;  
            type += adapter.getViewTypeCount();  
        }  
        return -1;  
    }  

    public boolean areAllItemsSelectable() {  
        return false;  
    }  

    public boolean isEnabled(int position) {  
        return (getItemViewType(position) != TYPE_SECTION_HEADER);  
    }  

    @Override  
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {  
        int sectionnum = 0;  
        for(Object section : this.sections.keySet()) {  
            Adapter adapter = sections.get(section);  
            int size = adapter.getCount() + 1;  

            // check if position inside this section   
            if(position == 0) return headers.getView(sectionnum, convertView, parent);  
            if(position < size) return adapter.getView(position - 1, convertView, parent);  

            // otherwise jump into next section  
            position -= size;  
            sectionnum++;  
        }  
        return null;  
    }  

    @Override  
    public long getItemId(int position) {  
        return position;  
    }  

}
```

Which is then called by the following code:

```
SeparatedListAdapter adapter;

    public Map<String,?> createItem(String name) {  
        Map<String,String> item = new HashMap<String,String>();  
        item.put(ITEM_VALUE, name);
        return item;
    } 

List<Map<String,?>> item = new LinkedList<Map<String,?>>();
item.add(createItem("value"));
adapter.addSection("Header", new SimpleAdapter(this, item, R.layout.list_item, new String[] { "value" }, new int[] { R.id.lblValue }));
listview.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Now until recently, my `list_header` xml file had a `TextView` root element. At this point it was working perfectly. But then I wanted to expand on the header to contain more than one view. The new root element of the `list_header` is now a `RelativeLayout`.

Now when I try and start the activity, I get the following exception:  `IllegalStateException: ArrayAdapter requires the resource ID to be a Text View`. I understand the error but since I am relatively new to Android, I am unsure how to get around this problem. How can I modify my adapter to handle headers which contain a `RelativeLayout` as the root element, instead of a `TextView`?

Edit:
I believe the answer lies in the constructor method of the adapter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Edit: I believe the answer lies in the constructor method of the
>   adapter?

Precisely, you should use [this one](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#ArrayAdapter%28android.content.Context,%20int,%20int%29):

```
headers = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context, R.layout.list_header, R.id.the_id_of_textview);
```

Also, have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9280965/arrayadapter-requires-the-resource-id-to-be-a-textview-xml-problems/9282069#9282069).