# ArrayAdapter Causes ClassCastException

Tags: android, android-layout, android-arrayadapter, android-adapter

I have an AutoCompleteTextView inside a `RelativeLayout` inside a `FrameLayout`.  I want to populate the completion list using a class declared as follows:

```
public class AutoCompleteAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> implements Filterable {
 ...
 public AutoCompleteAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId) {
    super(context, textViewResourceId);
    data = new ArrayList<String>();
 }
 ...
}
```

I attached the adapter as follows:

```
AutoCompleteTextView tv = (AutoCompleteTextView) v.findViewById(R.id.editTextClient);
    AutoCompleteAdapter adapter = new AutoCompleteAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.fragment_main_right);
    tv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

where R.layout.fragment_main_right is the enclosing `FrameLayout` mentioned above.  When I start to input text, I get a `ClassCastException` with the following message: `"android.widget.FrameLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.TextView"`.  I understand this to mean that the second parameter in the `ArrayAdapter` constructor should be the id of something derived from a `TextView`.  All the examples show this parameter as being the enclosing layout.  Can someone clear up my confusion?

Comment: This should explain the reason for the cast exception http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9280965/arrayadapter-requires-the-resource-id-to-be-a-textview-xml-problems/9282069#9282069 . Also that layout that you pass to the adapter is the row layout and you probably don't want to use the layout containing the actual auto complete widget.

Comment: post and read your stacktrace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the second parameter in your adapter constructor, pass in android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line or android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 instead.

The hint is given away that it expects a textview by the name of the parameter: textViewResoureceId.