# Changing from ArrayAdapter<String> with a textView to ArrayAdapter<String> with LinearLayout. Class cast exception

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, android-arrayadapter, layoutparams

My code is currently using an ArrayAdapter with a single TextView in layout file, and everything works well.

My current layout is as follows (R.layout.list_header):

```
<TextView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/list_header_title"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:paddingTop="2dip"
android:paddingBottom="2dip"
android:paddingLeft="5dip"
android:textSize="16sp"
android:textColor="#ffffff"
style="?android:attr/listSeparatorTextViewStyle" />
```

And I create my adapter this way:

```
new ArrayAdapter<String>(context, R.layout.list_header);
```

Now, I want to add a picture in my adapter, at the left side of my textView. I first looked at this thread that helped me use more than just a textView:
["ArrayAdapter requires the resource ID to be a TextView" xml problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9280965/arrayadapter-requires-the-resource-id-to-be-a-textview-xml-problems)

My new layout is now as follows:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal" >    

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/list_header_picture"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:contentDescription="line_logo" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/list_header_title"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="2dip"
    android:paddingBottom="2dip"
    android:paddingLeft="5dip"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    style="?android:attr/listSeparatorTextViewStyle" />

</LinearLayout>
```

And the adapter is created this way:

```
new ArrayAdapter<String>(context, R.layout.list_header, R.id.list_header_title);
```

And this is where I get the error java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout$Params cannot be cast to android.widget.AbsListView$LayoutParams.
I can't see what is wrong here. I tried to remove the imageView, but this doesn't change anything.

Any idea on what could be causing the problem?

EDIT:

Here is my adapter class:

```
public class SeparatedListAdapter extends BaseAdapter
{
public final Map<String, Adapter> sections = new LinkedHashMap<String, Adapter>();
public final ArrayAdapter<String> headers;
public final static int TYPE_SECTION_HEADER = 0;

public SeparatedListAdapter(Context context) {
    headers = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context, R.layout.list_header);//, R.id.list_header_title);
}

public void addSection(String section, Adapter adapter) {
    this.headers.add(section);
    this.sections.put(section, adapter);
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    for (Object section : this.sections.keySet())
    {
        Adapter adapter = sections.get(section);
        int size = adapter.getCount() + 1;

        // check if position inside this section
        if (position == 0) return section;
        if (position < size) return adapter.getItem(position - 1);

        // otherwise jump into next section
        position -= size;
    }
    return null;
}

public int getCount() {
    // total together all sections, plus one for each section header
    int total = 0;
    for (Adapter adapter : this.sections.values())
        total += adapter.getCount() + 1;
    return total;
}

@Override
public int getViewTypeCount() {
    // assume that headers count as one, then total all sections
    int total = 1;
    for (Adapter adapter : this.sections.values())
        total += adapter.getViewTypeCount();
    return total;
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    int type = 1;
    for (Object section : this.sections.keySet())
    {
        Adapter adapter = sections.get(section);
        int size = adapter.getCount() + 1;

        // check if position inside this section
        if (position == 0) return TYPE_SECTION_HEADER;
        if (position < size) return type + adapter.getItemViewType(position - 1);

        // otherwise jump into next section
        position -= size;
        type += adapter.getViewTypeCount();
    }
    return -1;
}

public boolean areAllItemsSelectable() {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean isEnabled(int position) {
    //return (getItemViewType(position) != TYPE_SECTION_HEADER);
    return false;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    int sectionnum = 0;
    for (Object section : this.sections.keySet())
    {
        Adapter adapter = sections.get(section);
        int size = adapter.getCount() + 1;

        // check if position inside this section
        if (position == 0) {
            //CREATE HEADER VIEW
            View lHeaderView = headers.getView(sectionnum, convertView, parent);
            String headerText = ((TextView) lHeaderView.findViewById(R.id.list_header_title)).getText().toString();
            String currentLine = "highway";
            String currentDirection = "upwards";



            if (currentLine.startsWith("N")) {
                //((TextView) lHeaderView.findViewById(R.id.list_header_title)).setTextColor(Color.rgb(10, 10, 23));
                ((TextView) lHeaderView).setTextColor(Color.rgb(10, 10, 23));
                lHeaderView.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(42, 73, 144));
            } else {
                //((TextView) lHeaderView.findViewById(R.id.list_header_title)).setTextColor(Color.rgb(255, 255, 255));
                ((TextView) lHeaderView).setTextColor(Color.rgb(255, 255, 255));
                lHeaderView.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(10, 10, 23));
            }

            //return (TextView)lHeaderView.findViewById(R.id.list_header_title);
            return lHeaderView;


        } else if (position < size) {
            //CREATE DETAILS VIEW
            View lHeaderView = headers.getView(sectionnum, convertView, parent);
            String headerText = ((TextView) lHeaderView).getText().toString();

            String currentLine = "route";

            View lView = adapter.getView(position - 1, convertView, parent);
            lView.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(10, 10, 23));


            if (currentLine.startsWith("N")) {
                ((TextView) lView).setTextColor(Color.rgb(10, 10, 23));
                lView.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(42, 73, 144));
            } else {
                ((TextView) lView).setTextColor(Color.rgb(0, 0, 0));
                lView.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(10, 10, 23));
            }

            return lView;
        }

        // otherwise jump into next section
        position -= size;
        sectionnum++;
    }
    return null;
}


@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}
}
```

Comment: For that you have to make your custom adapter...

Comment: I have one, just added its code to my question.

Comment: why do you have an arrayadapter inside an adapter? You are not supposed to do that, nor do you really need to.

Comment: Because I was looking for a way to have headers in a list, and I found this tutorial, which I followed. http://jsharkey.org/blog/2008/08/18/separating-lists-with-headers-in-android-09/

Comment: It works well up to now. If I'm doing it wrong, do you have another method to create a list with headers like the one I'm trying to do?

Comment: In the meanwhile, I'll have a look at that:https://github.com/emilsjolander/StickyListHeaders

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem using this library:
https://github.com/emilsjolander/StickyListHeaders