# parse listview adapter you must supply a resource id for a textview

Tags: java, android, listview, adapter

I found a lot of same problem, but I don't really know the solution for my problem. I have a simple Costumer parse.com class, and want to list the names. (all of them.)

Logcat says:

```
05-02 19:31:46.534: E/ArrayAdapter(12816): You must supply a resource ID for a TextView
05-02 19:31:46.534: D/AndroidRuntime(12816): Shutting down VM
05-02 19:31:46.534: W/dalvikvm(12816): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41cd1700)
05-02 19:31:46.574: E/AndroidRuntime(12816): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-02 19:31:46.574: E/AndroidRuntime(12816): java.lang.IllegalStateException: ArrayAdapter requires the resource ID to be a TextView
```

I think there is a problem with my IDs. I never used Adapter before.

```
// RemoteDataTask AsyncTask
private class RemoteDataTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        mProgressDialog.setTitle("Wait! Listing customers!");
        mProgressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        mProgressDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = new ParseQuery<ParseObject>(
                "Customers");
        // query.orderByDescending("_created_at");
        try {
            ob = query.find();
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this,
                R.layout.activity_main);

        for (ParseObject customer : ob) {
            adapter.add((String) customer.get("name"));
        }
        listview.setAdapter(adapter);
        mProgressDialog.dismiss();
    }
```

activity_main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="com.csaba.noteapp.MainActivity"
tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvname"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Name:"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/etname"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvphone"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Phone:"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/etphone"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="number" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvcity"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="City:"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/etcity"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonlist"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="List of customers" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonadd"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Add costumer" />

  <ListView
    android:id="@+id/listview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
```

Comment: post `activity_main.xml`

Comment: ty, forgot it, sry (edited)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9280965/arrayadapter-requires-the-resource-id-to-be-a-textview-xml-problems. check this. What you require is the second part

Comment: also post the full stacktrace cause you could check that and the source code and the line at which it exception occurs

Comment: Looks like  `activity_main.xml` is set to the activity also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing a custom layout in your `ArrayAdapter`. Here you should pass the resource id of the textview on which you want to show the text. Thats why it is giving this error.

Just call the adapter this way.

```
listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this,
                R.layout.activity_main,R.id.tvname );
```

here `R.id.tvname` is the id of one of the textview in your `activity_main.xml`. Or you can create the custom adapter.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the constructor of `ArrayAdapter`

> public ArrayAdapter (Context context, int resource)
>
> Added in API level 1 Constructor
>
> Parameters context    The current context. resource   The resource ID for a
>   layout file containing a TextView to use when instantiating views.

Check the source

http://androidxref.com/4.4.2_r2/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.java

Look at line `387` which is exactly what the stacktrace says. You can check `createViewFromResource` and know what happens

What you need is a xml with TextView only

row.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 

/>
```

And then

```
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this,
            R.layout.row);
```

You could also have your custom adapter and customize the textview

Also check this

["ArrayAdapter requires the resource ID to be a TextView" xml problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9280965/arrayadapter-requires-the-resource-id-to-be-a-textview-xml-problems)