# Insert data in Listview - Xamarin

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have a small application that retrieves data from a server. This is done with an function i've build. This function returns a `List<string>`.

Now the issue that i am having.
I want to insert the list that i retrieve from my function into a `ListView`.

I'm using the code below to try this:

```
List<string> range = _connection.GetData("animals");
ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,Resource.Layout.dataView, range);
listView.SetAdapter (adapter);
```

Range is the list that i get from my function `GetData()`
Now i want to insert the data from the range list into my listview but as soon as i start the application en press the button to do this the application shuts down with this message `The application has stopped unexpectedly. Please try again.`. 
Can someone tell me what i am doeing wrong here or show me how i can insert the data into my listbox.

**Edit**

I checked the ouput of the application and it says the following:

```
[AndroidRuntime] java.lang.IllegalStateException: ArrayAdapter requires the resource ID to be a TextView
```

So i know why the application shuts down.
Can someone show me or tell me how i have to insert the data because the adapter requires an Textview to work.

**Edit**

This is my XML for my listview

```
<ListView
        android:minWidth="25px"
        android:minHeight="25px"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/dataListView" />
```

Thanks in advance

**Final Edit 10/9/2014**

After a lot of research en being pointed in the right direction i finnaly found out what i was doeing wrong.

This is how you insert data into an listview:

```
ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleListItem1, response);
            listView.Adapter = adapter;
```

The problem was that i used an outdated function `SetAdapter()`
To everyone in the comments/ awnsers thanks for the help.

Comment: can you share your logcat with us?

Comment: I've eddited the question

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9282069/3602047

Comment: Thanks for the awnser but is there i way to accomplish this with an listview

Comment: post your xml for `Resource.Layout.dataView`