# Android ListView in Navigation Drawer Layout

Tags: android, arrays, listview, android-arrayadapter, navigation-drawer

I tried to create a ListView populated with some strings that I read from an XML file a put in an ArrayList structure. I just want to show them as a list on screen.
When my code reach this instruction:

> MainList.setAdapter(itemsAdapter);

It just crash and I cannot understand why ... any idea, please?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ListView
 android:id="@+id/data_list"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent">
</ListView>

</RelativeLayout>


public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {
    Context ct;

    public HomeFragment(Context c){
     ct=c;  
    }



    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

      View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);


      ArrayList<Zone> zones = new ArrayList<Zone>();



      try{
        MY CODE
      }catch(Exception e){

      }

      ArrayList<String> items = new ArrayList<String>();

      for (Zone zn : zones){items.add(zn.name);}

      ArrayAdapter<String> itemsAdapter = 
              new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), R.layout.fragment_home,items);

      ListView MainList = (ListView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.data_list);
      MainList.setAdapter(itemsAdapter);

      return rootView;
    }
}
```

****EDIT****

```
10-01 17:55:36.757: E/ArrayAdapter(22387): You must supply a resource ID for a TextView
10-01 17:55:36.757: D/AndroidRuntime(22387): Shutting down VM
10-01 17:55:36.757: W/dalvikvm(22387): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x416198b0)
10-01 17:55:36.787: E/AndroidRuntime(22387): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-01 17:55:36.787: E/AndroidRuntime(22387): java.lang.IllegalStateException: ArrayAdapter requires the resource ID to be a TextView
10-01 17:55:36.787: E/AndroidRuntime(22387):    at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:386)
10-01 17:55:36.787: E/AndroidRuntime(22387):    at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:362)
10-01 17:55:36.787: E/AndroidRuntime(22387):    at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2177)
10-01 17:55:36.787: E/AndroidRuntime(22387):    at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1852)
10-01 17:55:36.787: E/AndroidRuntime(22387):    at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:687)
10-01 17:55:36.787: E/AndroidRuntime(22387):    at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:748)
10-01 17:55:36.787: E/AndroidRuntime(22387):    at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1667)
10-01 17:55:36.787: E/AndroidRuntime(22387):    at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2012)
10-01 17:55:36.787: E/AndroidRuntime(22387):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14472)
10-01 17:55:36.787: E/AndroidRuntime(22387):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4562)
10-01 17:55:36.787: E/AndroidRuntime(22387):    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1076)
10-01 17:55:36.787: E/AndroidRuntime(22387):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14472)
10-01 17:55:36.787: E/AndroidRuntime(22387):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4562)
10-01 17:55:36.787: E/AndroidRuntime(22387):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
10-01 17:55:36.787: E/AndroidRuntime(22387):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14472)
10-01 17:55:36.787: E/AndroidRuntime(22387):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4562)
10-01 17:55:36.787: E/AndroidRuntime(22387):    at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onLayout(DrawerLayout.java:801)
10-01 17:55:36.787: E/AndroidRuntime(22387):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14472)
10-01 17:55:36.787: E/AndroidRuntime(22387):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4562)
10-01 17:55:36.787: E/AndroidRuntime(22387):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
10-01 17:55:36.787: E/AndroidRuntime(22387):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14472)
10-01 17:55:36.787: E/AndroidRuntime(22387):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4562)
10-01 17:55:36.787: E/AndroidRuntime(22387):    at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onLayout(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:349)
10-01 17:55:36.787: E/AndroidRuntime(22387):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14472)
10-01 17:55:36.787: E/AndroidRuntime(22387):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4562)
10-01 17:55:36.787: E/AndroidRuntime(22387):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
10-01 17:55:36.787: E/AndroidRuntime(22387):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14472)
10-01 17:55:36.787: E/AndroidRuntime(22387):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4562)
10-01 17:55:36.787: E/AndroidRuntime(22387):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:1984)
10-01 17:55:36.787: E/AndroidRuntime(22387):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1738)
10-01 17:55:36.787: E/AndroidRuntime(22387):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1008)
10-01 17:55:36.787: E/AndroidRuntime(22387):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5509)
10-01 17:55:36.787: E/AndroidRuntime(22387):    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:749)
10-01 17:55:36.787: E/AndroidRuntime(22387):    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:562)
10-01 17:55:36.787: E/AndroidRuntime(22387):    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:532)
10-01 17:55:36.787: E/AndroidRuntime(22387):    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:735)
10-01 17:55:36.787: E/AndroidRuntime(22387):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
10-01 17:55:36.787: E/AndroidRuntime(22387):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
10-01 17:55:36.787: E/AndroidRuntime(22387):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-01 17:55:36.787: E/AndroidRuntime(22387):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5214)
10-01 17:55:36.787: E/AndroidRuntime(22387):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-01 17:55:36.787: E/AndroidRuntime(22387):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
10-01 17:55:36.787: E/AndroidRuntime(22387):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:739)
10-01 17:55:36.787: E/AndroidRuntime(22387):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:555)
10-01 17:55:36.787: E/AndroidRuntime(22387):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-01 17:55:36.787: E/AndroidRuntime(22387): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.RelativeLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.TextView
10-01 17:55:36.787: E/AndroidRuntime(22387):    at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:379)
10-01 17:55:36.787: E/AndroidRuntime(22387):    ... 44 more
```

*** EDIT 2 ***

Can I give different properties to the many textview that I put in my listview?

i.e. one textview with certain background property, another one with some particular font ... even some different behavior on click event?

Comment: can you post the log?

Comment: log added, tnkx for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify an id for your ArrayAdapter.

This question has been asked before, see this link: ["ArrayAdapter requires the resource ID to be a TextView" xml problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9280965/arrayadapter-requires-the-resource-id-to-be-a-textview-xml-problems)

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify an id for your ArrayAdapter.

This question has been asked before, see this link: "["ArrayAdapter requires the resource ID to be a TextView" xml problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9280965/arrayadapter-requires-the-resource-id-to-be-a-textview-xml-problems)

You should have something like:

```
ArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource, int textViewResourceId, T[] objects)
```

More info: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html

where your ID should be a TextView defined in your `R.layout.fragment_home` since it's your resource

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify your text view id and by mistake you give a relative layout id to textview, give a specific id to textview
ArrayAdapter requires the resource ID to be a TextView