# FATAL EXCEPTION: main java.lang.IllegalStateException: ArrayAdapter requires the resource ID to be a TextView

Tags: android

I am creating simple ListView in my user class, but everytime when I launch my application I get error in the logcat , which gives

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.IllegalStateException: ArrayAdapter requires the resource ID to be a TextView
```

I don't know why in the ArrayAdapter causes the error.I just followed this tutorial

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_list_view.htm

Thank you in advance.

```
package com.example.myemployee;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;



public class User extends Activity{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.user_layout);



        String[] countryArray = {"India", "Pakistan", "USA", "UK"};
        ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                R.layout.user_txtview, countryArray);

        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lstview_user);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    }

}
```

user_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent" >


    <ListView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/lstview_user" android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

user_txtview.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent">

</TextView>
```

Comment: as in provided tutorial ` TextView id is `android:id="@+id/label"` in user_txtview.xml` layout

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK,and the adapter is that okay ?

Comment: same problem ArrayAdapter﹕ You must supply a resource ID for a TextView

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Change this**

```
ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.user_txtview, countryArray);
```

**to this**

```
ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.listitem,R.id.textview, countryArray);
```

**listitem.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
</TextView>
```

The [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#ArrayAdapter%28android.content.Context,%20int,%20int,%20T%5B%5D%29) says:

> By default this class expects that the provided resource id references
>   a single TextView. If you want to use a more complex layout, use the
>   constructors that also takes a field id. That field id should
>   reference a TextView in the larger layout resource.

Comment: still having problem I already tried that.

Comment: In the adapter you are using are you using Textview or any other complex Ui Widgets?If not then try using new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
     android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,countryArray )

Comment: still having problem.

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    </TextView>

</LinearLayout> 
Java code:
ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.listitem,R.id.tv, countryArray);

Comment: @jemz Try creating a custom Adapter which extends BaseAdapter

Comment: @jemz Working perfect, look at this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9280965/arrayadapter-requires-the-resource-id-to-be-a-textview-xml-problems/28154445#28154445

Comment: Answer updated please check it.