# android ArrayAdapter requires the resource ID to be a TextView in spinner

Tags: java, android, xml, android-arrayadapter

I don't what is going on but I'm still getting this error when I test run my app on my phone.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: ArrayAdapter requires the resource ID to be a TextView
        at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:386)
        at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:362)
        at android.widget.AbsSpinner.onMeasure(AbsSpinner.java:197)
        at android.widget.Spinner.onMeasure(Spinner.java:507)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17448)
        at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:727)
        at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:463)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17448)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5465)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17448)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5465)
        at android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:453)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17448)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5465)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17448)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5465)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1436)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:722)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:613)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17448)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5465)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2560)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17448)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2031)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1189)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1402)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1077)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5884)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:767)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:580)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:550)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:753)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5312)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:901)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:696)
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.TextView
        at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:379)
            at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:362)
            at android.widget.AbsSpinner.onMeasure(AbsSpinner.java:197)
            at android.widget.Spinner.onMeasure(Spinner.java:507)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17448)
            at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:727)
            at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:463)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17448)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5465)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17448)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5465)
            at android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:453)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17448)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5465)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17448)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5465)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1436)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:722)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:613)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17448)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5465)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2560)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17448)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2031)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1189)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1402)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1077)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5884)
            at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:767)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:580)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:550)
            at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:753)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5312)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
```

I have tried many options including creating a baseAdapter for my spinner arraylist but nothing seems to work. Here is my custom arrayadapter where I think is the problem but I don't know:

```
public class SpinnerArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ContactsData> {
...
public View getCustomView(int position, ViewGroup parent, View convertView){

    View row = convertView;
    ContactsHolder holder = null;

    if(row == null){
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
        row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, parent, false);

        holder = new ContactsHolder();

        holder.name = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.contactName);
        holder.number = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.contactPhone);

        row.setTag(holder);
    }else{
        holder = (ContactsHolder)row.getTag();
    }

    ContactsData contactsData = data.get(position);

    holder.name.setText(contactsData.name);
    holder.number.setText(contactsData.number);
    return row;
}

static class ContactsHolder{
    TextView name;
    TextView number;
}
```

And here is my layout row.xml file:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/contactName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/contactPhone"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Thanks in advance.

initializing arrayadapter in mainactivity.java

```
ArrayList<ContactsData> contacts_data = new ArrayList<>();

    contacts_data.add(new ContactsData("lol", "2"));

    SpinnerArrayAdapter mAdapter = new SpinnerArrayAdapter(MainActivity.this, R.layout.row, contacts_data);

    mAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

    mySpinner.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

Comment: how do you initialize your array adapter?

Comment: can you post your Adapter's constructor ?

Answer (score 1):

you need to add the id of the `TextView` you would like to use

E.g.

```
SpinnerArrayAdapter mAdapter = new SpinnerArrayAdapter(MainActivity.this, R.layout.row, R.id. contactName, contacts_data);
```

and off course

```
public class SpinnerArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ContactsData> {
   public SpinnerArrayAdapter(Context c, int layoutId, int textViewId, ArrayList<ContactsData> data) {
        super(c, layoutId, textViewId, data);
        // other stuff
  } 
}
```

this is just a workaround for the super class, since you are taking care of the visualisation in your `getView`

Comment: is it possible to use 2 different textviews?

Comment: it is. You need the id just as workaround for the super class. The rest looks correct to me

Answer (score 0):

your layout file should contain only one textview and it cannot be wrapped under any layout like the below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        // other attributes of the TextView
        />
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9280965/arrayadapter-requires-the-resource-id-to-be-a-textview-xml-problems)

Comment: and how do I display 2 textviews in spinner