# Android: ArrayAdapter requires the resource ID to be a TextView?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, android-arrayadapter, illegalstateexception

I'm trying to implement a code in which a list of linear layouts are inserted in the list view by using the array adapter. Each linear layout contains two subviews. Here's the xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/list_item"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/list_icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/list_label"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:textSize="16sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Now in the fragment I created a code snippet like this.

```
    final String[] my_page_items = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.my_page_items);

    int[] my_page_icons = {
            R.mipmap.ic_about,
            R.mipmap.ic_app_settings,
            R.mipmap.ic_account_settings,
            R.mipmap.ic_logout
    };

    LinearLayout[] items = new LinearLayout[my_page_items.length];
    TextView[] labels = new TextView[my_page_items.length];
    ImageView[] icons = new ImageView[my_page_icons.length];

    for(int i=0; i<my_page_icons.length; i++) {
        items[i] = (LinearLayout) LayoutInflater.from(getActivity().getApplication()).inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
        labels[i] = (TextView) items[i].findViewById(R.id.list_label);
        icons[i] = (ImageView) items[i].findViewById(R.id.list_icon);

        labels[i].setText(my_page_items[i]);
        icons[i].setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(my_page_icons[i]));
    }


    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<>(getActivity(), R.layout.list_item, items));
    lv = getListView();

    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

    });
```

When I run this code, I get the the following in the logcat.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: ArrayAdapter requires the resource ID to be a TextView
```

How should this problem be solved?

Answer (score 0):

In

```
new ArrayAdapter<>(getActivity(), R.layout.list_item, items)
```

`R.Layout.list_item` must be the id of a xml layout file containing only a `TextView`(the TextView can't be wrapped by another layout, like a LinearLayout, RelativeLayout etc!),

**EDIT**  possible solution :

If you want your list row layout to be something a little different then a simple TextView widget use this constructor:

```
new ArrayAdapter<>(getActivity(), R.layout.list_item, R.id.id_of_your_textview items)
```

where you supply the id of a layout that can contain various views, but also must contain a TextView with and id(the third parameter) that you pass to your ArrayAdapter so it can know where to put the Strings in the row layout.

Comment: Any suggestions for the solutions then?

Comment: you can create custom BaseAdapter

Comment: you can refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9280965/arrayadapter-requires-the-resource-id-to-be-a-textview-xml-problems for this error