# cannot find symbol variable array

Tags: java, android, android-studio

In android studio I am trying to create a college app that will contain different screens containing information. I have created a drawer but am unable to add items to the drawer because of the following line of code:

```
mApplicationOptions = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.application_options);
```

everything else works in my program except the array part under array `I get the error cannot find symbol variable array`. How can I resolve this in order to use the array to populate the list in my navigation drawer.

Thanks!

Comment: pls show your strings.xml

Answer (score 0):

Did you define the array in your app's resources ? You can do so by declaring an array in `strings.xml`, for example :

```
<string-array name="application_options">
    <item>one</item>
    <item>two</item>
    <item>three</item>
</string-array>
```

Documentation [HERE](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html#StringArray).

I hope this helps, captain ;)

Comment: I have done that however when I add items they not only do not show up but the app also crashes when run. ;(

Comment: <string-array name="application_options">
    <item>Profile</item>
    <item>Guardian</item>
    <item>DOB</item>
</string-array>

Comment: When run the app crashes and android studio gives me the error "ArrayAdapter requires the resource ID to be a TextView"

Comment: That's a different issue, you can find this when googling the error message : http://stackoverflow.com/q/9280965/1178337