# (ArrayAdapter requires the resource ID to be a TextView) but I am only using ListView

Tags: java, android, listview

I am getting `ArrayAdapter requires the resource ID to be a TextView` when running my application on a real device.

I am only using the ArrayAdapter regarding a ListView, having no TextView whatsoever in my design. Could you please take a look on my .java and logcat and see if you can spot the problem? Let me know if you need anything else. Thank you!

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.mihaianca.btcar;

//imports
import android.Manifest;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothManager;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;

import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothServerSocket;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.UUID;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.util.Log;
import java.util.Set;
import android.widget.AdapterView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    //variables-not using all of them but some are required in many examples for finding the MAC address
    Handler bluetoothIn;
    final int handlerState = 0;
    private BluetoothAdapter BA;
    Context context = this;
    private BluetoothManager BM;
    private BluetoothSocket btSocket = null;
    private ConnectedThread mConnectedThread;
    private static final UUID BTMODULEUUID = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");
    //list for addresses
    private static final String TAG = "DeviceListActivity";
    public static String EXTRA_DEVICE_ADDRESS = "device_address";
    private ArrayAdapter<String> mNewDevicesArrayAdapter;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> pairedDevicesArrayAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { //here I define my buttons

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        setResult(Activity.RESULT_CANCELED);

        final Button upb = (Button) findViewById(R.id.up);
        upb.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mConnectedThread.write("1");
            }
        });
        final Button downb = (Button) findViewById(R.id.down);
        downb.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mConnectedThread.write("2");
            }
        });
        final Button rightb = (Button) findViewById(R.id.right);
        rightb.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mConnectedThread.write("3");
            }
        });
        final Button leftb = (Button) findViewById(R.id.left);
        leftb.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mConnectedThread.write("4");
            }
        });
        final Button connectb = (Button) findViewById(R.id.connect);
        connectb.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                checkBTState();
                doDiscovery();
                v.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        });


        pairedDevicesArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.activity_main);
        mNewDevicesArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.activity_main);

        ListView pairedListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.paired_devices);
        pairedListView.setAdapter(pairedDevicesArrayAdapter);
        pairedListView.setOnItemClickListener(mDeviceClickListener);

        ListView newDevicesListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.new_devices);
        newDevicesListView.setAdapter(mNewDevicesArrayAdapter);
        newDevicesListView.setOnItemClickListener(mDeviceClickListener);

        // Register for broadcasts when a device is discovered
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
        this.registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);

        // Register for broadcasts when discovery has finished
        filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED);
        this.registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);

        // Get the local Bluetooth adapter
        BM = (BluetoothManager) context.getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE);
        BA = BM.getAdapter();
        checkBTState();
        if(BA!= null) {
            // Get a set of currently paired devices
            Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices = BA.getBondedDevices();

            // If there are paired devices, add each one to the ArrayAdapter
            if (pairedDevices.size() > 0) {
                for (BluetoothDevice device : pairedDevices) {
                    pairedDevicesArrayAdapter.add(device.getName() + "\n" + device.getAddress());
                }
            } else {
                String noDevices = getResources().getText(R.string.none_paired).toString();
                pairedDevicesArrayAdapter.add(noDevices);
            }

            if(EXTRA_DEVICE_ADDRESS != "device_address") {
                BluetoothDevice device = BA.getRemoteDevice(EXTRA_DEVICE_ADDRESS);

                try {
                    btSocket = createBluetoothSocket(device);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Socket creation failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                // Establish the Bluetooth socket connection.
                try {
                    btSocket.connect();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    try {
                        if(btSocket!=null)
                        btSocket.close();
                    } catch (IOException e2) {
                        //insert code to deal with this
                    }
                }
                mConnectedThread = new ConnectedThread(btSocket);
                mConnectedThread.start();
            }

        }
    }

    private BluetoothSocket createBluetoothSocket(BluetoothDevice device) throws IOException { //something I have seen in one example I tried to copy

        return device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(BTMODULEUUID);
        //creates secure outgoing connecetion with BT device using UUID
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();

        // Make sure we're not doing discovery anymore
        if (BA != null) {
            BA.cancelDiscovery();
        }

        // Unregister broadcast listeners
        this.unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        try {
            if(btSocket!=null)
            //Don't leave Bluetooth sockets open when leaving activity
            btSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e2) {
            //insert code to deal with this
        }
    }

    private class ConnectedThread extends Thread {
        private final InputStream mmInStream;
        private final OutputStream mmOutStream;

        //creation of the connect thread
        public ConnectedThread(BluetoothSocket socket) {
            InputStream tmpIn = null;
            OutputStream tmpOut = null;

            try {
                //Create I/O streams for connection
                tmpIn = socket.getInputStream();
                tmpOut = socket.getOutputStream();
            } catch (IOException e) {
            }

            mmInStream = tmpIn;
            mmOutStream = tmpOut;
        }

        public void run() {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[256];
            int bytes;

            // Keep looping to listen for received messages
            while (true) {
                try {
                    bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer);            //read bytes from input buffer
                    String readMessage = new String(buffer, 0, bytes);
                    // Send the obtained bytes to the UI Activity via handler
                    bluetoothIn.obtainMessage(handlerState, bytes, -1, readMessage).sendToTarget();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        //write method
        public void write(String input) {
            byte[] msgBuffer = input.getBytes();           //converts entered String into bytes
            try {
                mmOutStream.write(msgBuffer);                //write bytes over BT connection via outstream
            } catch (IOException e) {
                //if you cannot write, close the application
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Connection Failure", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                finish();
            }
        }
    }

    private void doDiscovery() {
        Log.d(TAG, "doDiscovery()");

        // Indicate scanning in the title
        setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);

        // If we're already discovering, stop it
        if(BA!=null)
            if (BA.isDiscovering()) {
                BA.cancelDiscovery();
            }

        // Request discover from BluetoothAdapter
        BA.startDiscovery();
    }

    /**
     * The on-click listener for all devices in the ListViews
     */
    private AdapterView.OnItemClickListener mDeviceClickListener
            = new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> av, View v, int arg2, long arg3) {
            // Cancel discovery because it's costly and we're about to connect
            BA.cancelDiscovery();

            // Get the device MAC address, which is the last 17 chars in the View
            String info = ((TextView) v).getText().toString();
            String address = info.substring(info.length() - 17);

            // Create the result Intent and include the MAC address
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.putExtra(EXTRA_DEVICE_ADDRESS, address);

            // Set result and finish this Activity
            setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, intent);
            finish();
        }
    };

    private final BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String action = intent.getAction();

            // When discovery finds a device
            if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
                // Get the BluetoothDevice object from the Intent
                BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
                // If it's already paired, skip it, because it's been listed already
                if (device.getBondState() != BluetoothDevice.BOND_BONDED) {
                    mNewDevicesArrayAdapter.add(device.getName() + "\n" + device.getAddress());
                }
                // When discovery is finished, change the Activity title
            } else if (BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED.equals(action)) {
                setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false);
                setTitle(R.string.select_device);
                if (mNewDevicesArrayAdapter.getCount() == 0) {
                    String noDevices = getResources().getText(R.string.none_found).toString();
                    mNewDevicesArrayAdapter.add(noDevices);
                }
            }
        }
    };

    private void checkBTState() {
        // Check device has Bluetooth and that it is turned on
        BA=BM.getAdapter();
        if(BA==null) {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Device does not support Bluetooth", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            if (BA.isEnabled()) {
                Log.d(TAG, "...Bluetooth ON...");
            } else {
                //Prompt user to turn on Bluetooth
                Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
                startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, 1);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

**Logcat output:**

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                       Process: com.example.mihaianca.btcar, PID: 9961
                                                                       java.lang.IllegalStateException: ArrayAdapter requires the resource ID to be a TextView
                                                                           at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:393)
                                                                           at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:369)
                                                                           at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2346)
                                                                           at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1876)
                                                                           at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:702)
                                                                           at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:763)
                                                                           at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1671)
                                                                           at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2148)
                                                                           at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16636)
                                                                           at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
                                                                           at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:336)
                                                                           at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:273)
                                                                           at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16636)
                                                                           at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
                                                                           at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:336)
                                                                           at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:273)
                                                                           at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16636)
                                                                           at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
                                                                           at android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onLayout(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:435)
                                                                           at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16636)
                                                                           at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
                                                                           at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:336)
                                                                           at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:273)
                                                                           at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16636)
                                                                           at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
                                                                           at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1735)
                                                                           at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1579)
                                                                           at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1488)
                                                                           at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16636)
                                                                           at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
                                                                           at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:336)
                                                                           at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:273)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onLayout(PhoneWindow.java:2678)
                                                                           at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16636)
                                                                           at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
                                                                           at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2179)
                                                                           at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1939)
                                                                           at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1115)
                                                                           at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6023)
                                                                           at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:858)
                                                                           at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:670)
                                                                           at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:606)
                                                                           at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:844)
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5422)
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
                                                                        Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.FrameLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.TextView
                                                                           at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:386)
                                                                           at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:369) 
                                                                           at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2346) 
                                                                           at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1876) 
                                                                           at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:702) 
                                                                           at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:763) 
                                                                           at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1671) 
                                                                           at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2148) 
                                                                           at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16636) 
                                                                           at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437) 
                                                                           at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:336) 
                                                                           at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:273) 
                                                                           at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16636) 
                                                                           at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437) 
                                                                           at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:336) 
                                                                           at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:273) 
                                                                           at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16636) 
                                                                           at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437) 
                                                                           at android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onLayout(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:435) 
                                                                           at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16636) 
                                                                           at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437) 
                                                                           at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:336) 
                                                                           at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:273) 
                                                                           at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16636) 
                                                                           at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437) 
                                                                           at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1735) 
                                                                           at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1579) 
                                                                           at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1488) 
                                                                           at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16636) 
                                                                           at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437) 
                                                                           at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:336) 
                                                                           at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:273) 
                                                                           at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onLayout(PhoneWindow.java:2678) 
                                                                           at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16636) 
                                                                           at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437) 
                                                                           at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2179) 
                                                                           at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1939) 
                                                                           at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1115) 
                                                                           at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6023) 
                                                                           at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:858) 
                                                                           at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:670) 
                                                                           at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:606) 
                                                                           at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:844) 
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5422) 
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["ArrayAdapter requires the resource ID to be a TextView" xml problems](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9280965/arrayadapter-requires-the-resource-id-to-be-a-textview-xml-problems)

Answer (score 0):

ArrayAdapter constructors 2nd paramter expects resource ID of a layout file containing a TextView to use when instantiating views. You can use predefined layout like

```
 yourAdapterObject = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace your below lines

```
pairedDevicesArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.activity_main);
mNewDevicesArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.activity_main);
```

with

```
pairedDevicesArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,android.R.id.text1,YOURPAIREDDEVICESARRAYLIST);
mNewDevicesArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,android.R.id.text1,YOURDEVICESARRAYLIST);
```

Comment: what does "android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1" and  "android.R.id.text1" stand for? Should I replace that with "R.layout.activity_main" and "pairedListView"?