# Spinner is not working

Tags: android

I am trying to create a simple spinner but its showing an error. I have created an activity in my project.

My MainActivity class :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Spinner sp;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        list.add("K");
        list.add("J");
        list.add("S");
        list.add("B");
        list.add("G");
        list.add("F");
        list.add("G");
        list.add("D");
        list.add("C");
        list.add("M");
        sp=(Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.activity_main,list);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.activity_main);
        sp.setAdapter(adapter);

        sp.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                String label = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
                Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(),"You are selected "+label,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

here is my activity_main.xml where i added a spinner:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.firebase.ashik.dropdownlistviewvaluecount.MainActivity">

    <Spinner
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="81dp"
        android:id="@+id/spinner" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

and showing this fatal error :

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: ArrayAdapter requires the resource ID to be a TextView

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["ArrayAdapter requires the resource ID to be a TextView" xml problems](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9280965/arrayadapter-requires-the-resource-id-to-be-a-textview-xml-problems)

Comment: adapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.activity_main); remove this line

Comment: you are inflating wrong layout , change this

 `ArrayAdapter<String> adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.activity_main,list);`

to this

`ArrayAdapter<String> adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.simple_spinner_item,list);`

Comment: R.simple_spinner_item is the in build layout .it will act as drop-down item on the spinner list.

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

```
 ArrayAdapter<String> adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.simple_spinner_item,list);
```

Comment: Why you said this answer.? Make question owner understand.

Answer (score 1):

This following line is where you are getting exception:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.activity_main,list);
```

change this to:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,list);
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace your ArrayAdapter line with one of the below :

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,list);

ArrayAdapter<String> adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,list);
```