# List views and custom adapters: resource id for textview

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I'm trying to implement my own `ListView` design with a custom adapter. But whenever I run my program, I get this error *"ArrayAdapter: You must supply a resource ID for a TextView"*.

Here is my Custom Adapter

```
  public class LayoutAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {

        List list = new ArrayList();

        public LayoutAdapter (Context context, int resource) {
            super(context,resource);
        }

        static class DataHandler {
            TextView accountName;
            TextView availableBalance;
            TextView totalBalance;
        }

        @Override
        public void add(Object object) {
            super.add(object);
            list.add(object);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return this.list.size();
        }

        @Nullable
        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return this.list.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            View row;
            row = convertView;
            DataHandler handler;
            if(convertView == null) {
                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)this.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_layout,parent,false);
                handler = new DataHandler();
                handler.accountName = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.account_name);
                handler.availableBalance = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.available_balance);
                handler.totalBalance = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.total_balance);
                row.setTag(handler);
            }
            else {
                handler = (DataHandler)row.getTag();
            }

            Account account;
            account = (Account)this.getItem(position);
            handler.accountName.setText(account.returnName());
            handler.availableBalance.setText("Available Balance: $"+account.returnAvailableBalance());
            handler.totalBalance.setText("Total Balance: $"+account.returnTotalBalance());

            return row;
        }
}
```

Here is my custom_layout.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:padding="8dp">

    <TextView
        android:text="@string/str_account_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/account_name"
        android:height="80dp"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/account_name">

        <TextView
            android:text="@string/str_available_balance"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/available_balance"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:paddingTop="30dp" />

        <TextView
            android:text="@string/str_total_balance"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/total_balance"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:layout_gravity="right" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout >
```

Here is my main activity

```
LayoutAdapter adapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_screen);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

    adapter = new LayoutAdapter(getApplicationContext(),R.layout.custom_layout);
    ArrayList<Account> accounts = new ArrayList<>();
    accounts.add(new Account ("Checking",5.00));
    accounts.add(new Account ("Cash",50.00));

    Account acc1 = new Account("Checking",5.00);
    Account acc2 = new Account("Cash",50.00);

    adapter.add(acc1);
    adapter.add(acc2);

    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: You can extend `BaseAdapter` instead of `ArrayAdapter` so you won't have to worry about a `resourceID` since you're using your own layout.

Comment: Which use of my "R.layout.custom_layout" is wrong?

Comment: Take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/a/9282069/1552587

Comment: but I want to be able to use an array of my own class which is why im not using ArrayAdapter which only takes string arrays

Comment: I've wanted you to look at that answer to see why you're getting that error. The error is caused because your layout is invalid, in order to use that layout it has to contain only a `TextView`

Comment: but then how am i able to create a layout with multiple text views?

Comment: Extend `BaseAdapter` instead of `ArrayAdapter`.

Comment: ok thank you, ill try that

Comment: i did that and it worked i love you so much you have no idea

Comment: <33333333333333

Comment: Great. I'm glad I could help. Good luck.