# ArrayAdapter.add() crashes Android app

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

I'm new with developing Java in Android Studio, so I'm learning by folowing tutorials. I am now creating an App to control a robot and I want to implement Bluetooth functionality. So I started a tutorial about bluetooth using Harry's tutorial: [Harry's tutorial](https://wingoodharry.wordpress.com).

After learning some Android Studio knowledge I created different Fragments in stead of multiply activity's. The problem now is that i get stuk when calling `ArrayAdapter.add();`. This function receives a String wright? So why is my app always crashing, Calling the `mPairedDevicesArrayAdapter.add(deviceString)`.

When debugging the code the program nicely get's the device name and MAC address. It log's it nicely in the debug monitor so `deviceString` is not the problem right? Other people say you need to place the String into a list, but the Android documents says that when the right contructor was called it can receive just a String.

Can somebody help me with this problem. Here's my bluetoothFragment class and the .xml file.

```
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Set;

/**
 * Created by rbesten on 5/2/2017.
 */

public class BluetoothFragment extends Fragment {
    // textview for connection status
    TextView textConnectionStatus;
    ListView pairedListView;

//An EXTRA to take the device MAC to the next activity
public static String EXTRA_DEVICE_ADDRESS;

// Member fields
private BluetoothAdapter mBtAdapter;
private ArrayAdapter<String> mPairedDevicesArrayAdapter;

String deviceString = "Test if it works";

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate( R.layout.fragment_bluetooth, container, false );
    return rootView;
}

public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    textConnectionStatus = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.connecting);
    textConnectionStatus.setTextSize(40);

    //Initialize array adapter for paired devices
    mPairedDevicesArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getContext(), R.layout.device_name);

    // Find and set up the ListView for paired devices
    pairedListView = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.paired_devices);
    pairedListView.setAdapter(mPairedDevicesArrayAdapter);
    //pairedListView.setOnItemClickListener(mDeviceClickListener);
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    //check BT status at onResume in case something has changed while app was paused etc
    checkBTState();

    mPairedDevicesArrayAdapter.clear();// clears the array so items aren't duplicated when resuming from onPause

    textConnectionStatus.setText(" "); //makes the textview blank

    //Get the local Bluetooth adapter
    mBtAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

    // Get a set of currently paired devices and append to pairedDevices list
    Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices = mBtAdapter.getBondedDevices();

    // Add previously paired devices to the array
    if (pairedDevices.size() > 0) {
        getActivity().findViewById(R.id.title_paired_devices).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE );//make title viewable

        for(BluetoothDevice device : pairedDevices){
            deviceString = (device.getName() + "\n" + device.getAddress() );

            mPairedDevicesArrayAdapter.add(deviceString);
            mPairedDevicesArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

    } else {
        mPairedDevicesArrayAdapter.add("no devices paired");
        mPairedDevicesArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}

//method to check if the device has Bluetooth and if it is on.
//Prompts the user to turn it on if it is off
private void checkBTState() {
    // Check device has Bluetooth and that it is turned on
    mBtAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(); // CHECK THIS OUT THAT IT WORKS!!!
    if (mBtAdapter == null) {
        Toast.makeText( getActivity().getBaseContext(), "Device does not support Bluetooth", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
        getActivity().finish();
    } else {
        if (!mBtAdapter.isEnabled()) {
            //Prompt user to turn on Bluetooth
            Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent( BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE );
            startActivityForResult( enableBtIntent, 1 );
        }
    }
}
```

And the .XML file!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title_paired_devices"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Select btSerial device from paired devices:"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:background="#666"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/paired_devices"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:stackFromBottom="false"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/connecting"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/infoText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="If no devices are listed please pair your device in Android settings"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center">

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

The debuggers information is:

```
this = {BluetoothFragment@4820} "BluetoothFragment{4e73664 #3 id=0x7f0b005e android:switcher:2131427422:3}"
pairedDevices = {Collections$UnmodifiableSet@4822}  size = 2
device = {BluetoothDevice@4823} "50:32:75:DA:15:4A"
mPairedDevicesArrayAdapter = {ArrayAdapter@4824} 
mBtAdapter = {BluetoothAdapter@4825} 
deviceString = "Test if it works"
```

And the crashlog:

```
05-03 10:10:32.364 32255-32255/com.example.rbesten.solscanrobot D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
05-03 10:10:32.367 32255-32255/com.example.rbesten.solscanrobot E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                  Process: com.example.rbesten.solscanrobot, PID: 32255
                                                                                  java.lang.IllegalStateException: ArrayAdapter requires the resource ID to be a TextView
                                                                                      at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:401)
                                                                                      at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:371)
                                                                                      at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2494)
                                                                                      at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1349)
                                                                                      at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1250)
                                                                                      at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20084)
                                                                                      at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6282)
                                                                                      at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1705)
                                                                                      at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:797)
                                                                                      at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:657)
                                                                                      at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20084)
                                                                                      at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1658)
                                                                                      at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20084)
                                                                                      at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6282)
                                                                                      at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:214)
                                                                                      at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:139)
                                                                                      at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20084)
                                                                                      at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6282)
                                                                                      at android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:393)
                                                                                      at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20084)
                                                                                      at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6282)
                                                                                      at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:214)
                                                                                      at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20084)
                                                                                      at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6282)
                                                                                      at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1705)
                                                                                      at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:797)
                                                                                      at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:657)
                                                                                      at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20084)
                                                                                      at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6282)
                                                                                      at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:214)
                                                                                      at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onMeasure(DecorView.java:766)
                                                                                      at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20084)
                                                                                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2640)
                                                                                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1577)
                                                                                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1846)
                                                                                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1462)
                                                                                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6965)
                                                                                      at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:907)
                                                                                      at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:709)
                                                                                      at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:644)
                                                                                      at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:893)
                                                                                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:836)
                                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
                                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:203)
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6247)
                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1063)
                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:924)
                                                                                   Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.TextView
                                                                                      at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:388)
                                                                                      at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:371) 
                                                                                      at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2494) 
                                                                                      at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1349) 
                                                                                      at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1250) 
                                                                                      at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20084) 
                                                                                      at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6282) 
                                                                                      at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1705) 
                                                                                      at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:797) 
                                                                                      at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:657) 
                                                                                      at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20084) 
                                                                                      at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1658) 
                                                                                      at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20084) 
                                                                                      at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6282) 
                                                                                      at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:214) 
                                                                                      at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:139) 
                                                                                      at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20084) 
                                                                                      at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6282) 
                                                                                      at android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:393) 
                                                                                      at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20084) 
                                                                                      at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6282) 
                                                                                      at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:214) 
                                                                                      at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20084) 
                                                                                      at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6282) 
                                                                                      at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1705) 
                                                                                      at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:797) 
                                                                                      at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:657) 
                                                                                      at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20084) 
                                                                                      at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6282) 
                                                                                      at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:214) 
                                                                                      at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onMeasure(DecorView.java:766) 
                                                                                      at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20084) 
                                                                                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2640) 
                                                                                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1577) 
                                                                                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1846) 
                                                                                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1462) 
                                                                                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6965) 
                                                                                      at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:907) 
                                                                                      at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:709) 
                                                                                      at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:644) 
                                                                                      at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:893) 
                                                                                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:836) 
                                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103) 
                                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:203) 
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6247) 
                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1063) 
                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:924)
```

Inside the device_name layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:textSize="18sp"
              android:padding="5dp">
    </TextView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Can you post the log

Comment: Yes sure! The debuggers log is: this = {BluetoothFragment@4820} "BluetoothFragment{4e73664 #3 id=0x7f0b005e android:switcher:2131427422:3}"
pairedDevices = {Collections$UnmodifiableSet@4822}  size = 2
device = {BluetoothDevice@4823} "50:32:75:DA:15:4A"
mPairedDevicesArrayAdapter = {ArrayAdapter@4824} 
mBtAdapter = {BluetoothAdapter@4825} 
deviceString = "Test if it works"

Comment: He/she meant the log of the crash, edit this into your post not as comment so it can get formatted properly

Comment: Post log exception(crash report)

Comment: what is inside R.layout.device_name file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

R.layout.device_name must be the id of a xml layout file containing only a TextView(the TextView can't be wrapped by another layout, like a LinearLayout, RelativeLayout etc!), something like this:

For further details you may refer below link
["ArrayAdapter requires the resource ID to be a TextView" xml problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9280965/arrayadapter-requires-the-resource-id-to-be-a-textview-xml-problems)

or you may try below id in array adapter constructor for testing purposes
android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 in place of R.layout.device_name

Hope that helps you

Comment: Thanks! The problem is solved! It is necessary to give the adapter the layout file and textView ID. `mPairedDevicesArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getContext(), R.layout.device_name, R.id.ArrayAdapterTextView);` And for the xml I add an ID field, `android:id="@+id/ArrayAdapterTextView"`. Thanks for referencing to [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9280965/arrayadapter-requires-the-resource-id-to-be-a-textview-xml-problems). This solved the problem.

Comment: I am glad it was helpful for you