# How do I dynamically populate a ListView with custom made CardViews?

Tags: java, android, list, android-arrayadapter, cardview

I'm trying to create a list with custom rows, but these rows are in fact CardViews. The CardViews have multiple textviews, half of which are user-set through a previous prompt, and an imageview:

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/custom_card"
android:clipToPadding="false"
android:clipChildren="false"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="20dp"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:clipChildren="false"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/cardItem"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:clipChildren="false"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0.0px"
        android:elevation="8dp"
        card_view:cardElevation="10dp"
        card_view:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false">

        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/gameIcon"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="200dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:contentDescription="Application Icon"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/nameDesc"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/roleDesc"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:text="TextView"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/roleTitle"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/rankDesc" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/regionDesc"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:text="TextView"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/regionTitle" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/rankTitle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:text="TextView"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/regionTitle"
                tools:text="@string/rankTitle" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/regionTitle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
                android:text="TextView"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/gameIcon"
                tools:text="@string/regionTitle" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/nameDesc"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:text="TextView"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/nameTitle" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/roleTitle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:text="TextView"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/rankDesc"
                tools:text="@string/roleTitle" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/rankDesc"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:text="TextView"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/rankTitle" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/nameTitle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:text="TextView"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                tools:text="@string/nameTitle" />
        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

The ListView will be filled dynamically by pressing a button and filling a prompt with text. I don't expect more than 5 rows in the list, so I chose a ListView instead of the better RecyclerView (which I had some problems in understanding and implementing).

Is there a way to use an adapter that could accomplish this task? I tried this:

```
ArrayList<View> listItems = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayAdapter<View> adapter;
[...]
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, R.layout.cardview_item, listItems);
ListView list = findViewById(R.id.profile_list);
list.setAdapter(adapter);
```

But I got the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: ArrayAdapter requires the resource ID to be a TextView
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["ArrayAdapter requires the resource ID to be a TextView" xml problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9280965/arrayadapter-requires-the-resource-id-to-be-a-textview-xml-problems)

Comment: @NileshRathod the link you provided is for a problem similar to mine, but still for only text as rows in the ListView. The solution provided in that post does not resolve my problem, as I'm asking about how to do something, not how to resolve an error. Thanks anyway

Comment: listItems should be ArrayList<CustomObject> and you have to define CustomObject for your own. In addtion, you need to make custom adapter or extends an adapter by overriding its getView() to tell which field in your CustomObject will fill up which TextView. I have blog about ListView here: http://programandroidlistview.blogspot.com/ Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

`ArrayAdapter` by default needs to interact with a TextView, not with a `CardView`. Look the [doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter)

Try to use a `BaseAdatper` that let you more free