# android - add border at bottom of TextView element

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, textview

How can I add a border at the bottom of the TextView in Android. The following is the XML code of my TextView.

```xml
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:text="Sales"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="10dp"
       />
```

and I am calling the XML like,

```
ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(mContext,
                       R.layout.layoutName, lables);
```

How to add the border below each content.

[image]

Any help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After using Suraj’s code, since I am using the array adaptor, I faced a new error “ Array adaptor requires the resource id to be a text view ". I fixed the error with the help of the following reference link.

["ArrayAdapter requires the resource ID to be a TextView" xml problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9280965/arrayadapter-requires-the-resource-id-to-be-a-textview-xml-problems).

Here is my java code,

```
ArrayAdapter<String>dataAdapter =  new ArrayAdapter<String>(mContext, R.layout.home_callus_selection,R.id.text, lables);
```

and the XML code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/opening_today_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="center"
        >
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv"
            android:layout_width="25dp"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:paddingLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"

            android:src="@drawable/callred" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/iv"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="Sales" />


    </RelativeLayout>
    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="#C1BFBF"
        />


</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using recyclerview you can use `DividerItemDecoration`.

add below code:

```
DividerItemDecoration dividerItemDecoration = new DividerItemDecoration(recyclerView.getContext(), DividerItemDecoration.HORIZONTAL);

recyclerView.addItemDecoration(dividerItemDecoration);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can put a view below your textview like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:text="Sales"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="10dp"
       />

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
       />

</LinearLayout>
```