# Adding data from firebase to listview in android

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to add data from firebase to listview in android. However, I'm having trouble adding data to the Listview and it crashes when I open the page. The data I'm trying to show is the food that was eaten by the user on the current date, like in this picture the user ate 5 apples and 1 white bread.
[image]

code here:

```
public class Breakfast extends AppCompatActivity {
private Button button1;
private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
private FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase;
private DatabaseReference databaseReference;
private ListView listView;
private ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
private ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter;
private Calendar calendar;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_breakfast);

    calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    final String currentDate = DateFormat.getDateInstance().format(calendar.getTime());
    firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    databaseReference = firebaseDatabase.getReference(firebaseAuth.getUid()).child("food").child(currentDate);
    listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
    arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, list);
    listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
    final FirebaseUser user=firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
    databaseReference.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String previousChildName) {
            String value = dataSnapshot.getValue(UserFoodInfo.class).toString();
            list.add(value);
            arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot, @Nullable String previousChildName) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot, @Nullable String previousChildName) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

        }
    });
```

user food class:

```
public class UserFoodInfo {
public String calories;
public String food_amount;

public UserFoodInfo() {

}

public UserFoodInfo(String calories, String food_amount){
    this.calories = calories;
    this.food_amount = food_amount;

}

public String getCalories() {
    return calories;
}

public String getFood_amount() {
    return food_amount;
}

public String toString(){
    return this.calories + "." + food_amount;
}
```

crash log:

```
E/ArrayAdapter: You must supply a resource ID for a TextView
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.test1, PID: 7639
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: ArrayAdapter requires the resource ID to be a TextView
        at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:401)
        at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:371)
        at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2491)
        at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:2018)
        at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:721)
        at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:782)
        at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1750)
        at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2249)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17838)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5754)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1982)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1826)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1735)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17838)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5754)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:383)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:321)
        at android.widget.ScrollView.onLayout(ScrollView.java:1562)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17838)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5754)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:383)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:321)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17838)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5754)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1982)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1826)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1735)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17838)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5754)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:383)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:321)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17838)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5754)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1982)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1826)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1735)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17838)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5754)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:383)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:321)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onLayout(DecorView.java:751)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17838)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5754)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2698)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2371)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1462)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6960)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:907)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:709)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:644)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:893)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:836)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:208)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6267)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1063)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:924)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.TwoLineListItem cannot be cast to android.widget.TextView
        at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:388)
        at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:371) 
        at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2491) 
        at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:2018) 
        at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:721) 
        at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:782) 
        at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1750) 
        at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2249) 
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17838) 
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5754) 
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1982) 
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1826) 
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1735) 
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17838) 
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5754) 
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:383) 
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:321) 
        at android.widget.ScrollView.onLayout(ScrollView.java:1562) 
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17838) 
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5754) 
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:383) 
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:321) 
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17838) 
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5754) 
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1982) 
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1826) 
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1735) 
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17838) 
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5754) 
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:383) 
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:321) 
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17838) 
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5754) 
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1982) 
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1826) 
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1735) 
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17838) 
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5754) 
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:383) 
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:321) 
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onLayout(DecorView.java:751) 
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17838) 
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5754) 
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2698) 
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2371) 
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1462) 
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6960) 
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:907) 
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:709) 
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:644) 
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:893) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:836) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:208) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6267) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1063) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:924)
```

Comment: Paste the app crash log pleas.

Comment: It seems that you forgot to initialize firebaseAuth. Also, FirebaseAuth has no method named getUid().

Comment: At which particular line of code does the error occur?

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["ArrayAdapter requires the resource ID to be a TextView" xml problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9280965/arrayadapter-requires-the-resource-id-to-be-a-textview-xml-problems)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the issue is in when you initliaze your arraAdapter sir, you need to uchange this

```
 arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);
```

becasue R.layout.simple_list_item_2 require two textviews to populate whereas R.layout.simple_list_item_1 requires one textview.